# .Net Web api exception message incomplete with angularjs 1.4 call

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

First, sorry for my poor english, i'm French.
Ionic mobile application call .net web api. 
When exception is thrown in web api, response content is incomplete with $http angular request compare with $.ajax jquery request.

**Jquery request :**

```
function getRef() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: httpRoot + "api/GetRef",
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $('#content').html($('#content').html() + "<br/>" + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (ex) {
      $('#content').html(ex.responseText);
    }
  });    
}
```

**Jquery response :**

```
{
  "message": "Une erreur s’est produite.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Problème d'exécution SQL",
  "exceptionType": "System.Exception",
  "stackTrace": " à G2HMOauth2.ModelsStock.StockRepository.GetStatus(String login) dans E:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\G2HMOauth2\\G2HMOauth2\\ModelsStock\\StockRepository.cs:ligne 213\r\n à G2HMOauth2.Controllers.OrdersController.GetRef() dans E:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\G2HMOauth2\\G2HMOauth2\\Controllers\\OrdersController.cs:ligne 50\r\n à lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n à System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n à System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n à System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n à System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n à System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n à System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
  "innerException": {
    "message": "Une erreur s’est produite.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Decimal' en type 'System.String'.",
    "exceptionType": "System.InvalidCastException",
    "stackTrace": " à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()\r\n à G2HMOauth2.ModelsStock.StockRepository.GetStatus(String login) dans E:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\G2HMOauth2\\G2HMOauth2\\ModelsStock\\StockRepository.cs:ligne 203"
  }
}
```

**Angularjs request :**

```
serv.connectIt = function (login) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  return $http({
    url: URLROOT.dev + 'api/GetRef',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.getAccessToken()},
    data: {}
  })
  .success(function (response) {
    serv.setItRef(response, login);
    deferred.resolve(response);
  })
  .error(function (err, status) {
    deferred.reject(err);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

**Angularjs response :**

```
{
    "message": "Une erreur s’est produite."
}
```

I have fixed this SQL error casting value types, what i want is, for the futures errors :

**How to get the same jquery complete response with angularjs ?**

Comment: seems like sql error in your server side. please add that code part as well

Comment: SQL error on casting value types. `type 'System.Decimal' en type 'System.String'`. Please have a closer look or update with some code.

Comment: Thank you for your responses but i have fix this bug. I have edited the post : the question is How to get the same jquery complete response with angularjs ?